# Attribute selector is not working (syntax error, unrecognized expression)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, syntax-error

I have function that iterates through a passed array via SSJS called "ps_data" one of the key value pairs contains a "urlencoded" value and for some reason it keep breaking my Jquery code.

I need this value to be passed exactly as it is.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each(ps_data, function (key, value) {
    $("input:radio[name="+key+"][value="+value+"]").prop("checked", true);
    console.log(key+ ":" + value);
  });
});
```

I get this error, even though the value is exactly as I need it and it is URL encoded. When I just use a regular string it works fine it is only with the value of the guid.

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

input:radio[name=guid][value=QyveK1%40vUnHeTQiwCn0IWGdEpmNqbUHL6cITnxlQHgI%3d]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the quotes for the [`[name=”value”]` selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).

This solves your issue:

```
$('input:radio[name="' + key + '"][value="' + value + '"]')
```

=>

```
$('input:radio[name="guid"][value="QyveK1%40vUnHeTQiwCn0IWGdEpmNqbUHL6cITnxlQHgI%3d"]')
```